# Drag and drop action in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a requirement to drag and item from a page and drop it at another location in the same web page which is developed in angular js

Can anyone let me know how do we do it in protractor?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple. You will need to use an action chain for this.

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem, target).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this:

```
  source = element you want to drag;
  target = element where you want to drop the source;

  browser.actions().dragAndDrop(source,target).mouseUp().perform();
```

Comment: You don't need the mouseUp() anymore ;)